# My android app requested background location and I do not even have background location permission

Tags: android

So, I have my own app [GPSRacer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=solutions.lunalabs.gpsracer) installed from playstore. Last time I used it was couple of days ago and I also restarted my phone in the meantime. This morning I got a notification that my app requested location in the background.

This is defenetly not possible as I do not have any code that could access location in the background in the first place. I only have those permissions requested:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

and those libraries that could potentially use this feature:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
```

Please note that I am currently working on update and would like to know if there is something I could do for this to not happen anymore. I do not want my users to think I am spying on them.

My phone: huawei P30 PRO

Thanks

Edit:

Maybe there is worth noticing that I had to mark that my app is not using background location services in play store developer console. But then, why would they try this on live installs?

[image: screenshot]

Edit 2:

I did some research and found this post from google:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/background-location-access

This is exact explanation how it should work yet it does not. Looks like a bug in android?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> this permission is used to get location updates from device, remove this.

Comment: This is base permission, without it app is not useable. Permission for accessing location in the background is not used nor requested and as you can see from notification it got location from the background.